# Why is MariaDB rejecting my SQL Backup?

Tags: debian, mariadb

I had to rebuild my Linode to Debian 9 since I couldn't get the sources from my previous question to work.

I used [this setup guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mariadb-php-lamp-stack-debian9) to reconfigure and reinstall everything to the new Debian distribution.

However, before doing this, I made a backup using

```
$ mysqldump --add-drop-table -h vps.sensation-experience.com -u wordpress -p wordpressDB > backup.sql
```

and saved it to my external hard drive.

After setting up MariaDB and running the secure script to create a root password, changing the hostname and hosts files, denying access from localhost, I tried running this line:

```
mysql --user wordpress --password < backup.sql
```

Note, I was already in the directory that the backup was located. The error I get is

```
 ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'wordpress'@'localhost'
```

Is there a way to work around this, or should I create a new database and just use an XML that I previously exported and inport that instead?

Comment: You denied access from localhost. Also, does the wordpress user even exist on your MariaDB instance with the correct permissions? Import the dump as `root` and then create the wordpress user and give it permissions.

Comment: So, can I change the hostname in MariaDB? If so, how? Also, you say I should try importing the dump as root, does that mean create a new SSH session with Root insteadd? Or, should I replace --user wordpress with --user root? If so, I already tried that and it said access denied.

Comment: Can you log into MariaDB as `root`? You also need to make sure that access from localhost is allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Give access to backup user like below,

```
MariaDB [(none)]> GRANT LOCK TABLES, SELECT ON *.* TO 'wordpress'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'your-password';

MariaDB [(none)]> flush privileges;
```

And after that try again.

Comment: that mean you are wordpressDB doesn't exists, create manually and try it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have a `wordpress` user in MariaDB, yet. And you might need more extensive permissions than your `wordpress` user has to restore a backup. I recommend to restore as database user `root`. On Debian systems the easiest way to log into MariaDB as `root` is to run `mysql` without any arguments while being logged into the system as user `root`:

```
root@tux:~$ echo "CREATE DATABASE wordpressDB;" | mysql
root@tux:~$ mysql < backup.sql
```

Note: Do *not* specify `localhost` as you want to connect through the unix domain socket which is being set up by default on Debian systems. No need to specify username/password since everyone with access to the unix domain socket (which by default should be only the system user `root`) automatically has `root` permissions in MariaDB.